# How do I combine these texture maps correctly in a material?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm working on a model for VRChat, and the uploader in Unity requests as few meshes and materials as possible. This wouldn't be a problem normally but I went with an outside tool to pull multiple models into blender and the materials for them are separated into their respective texture maps. I would appreciate assistance in combining these maps in blender for export into Unity and beyond.

I have the diffuse, normal, emissive, and specular maps and I've been trying to use the node view with materials to get them to mix correctly into the final material.

Comment: If the target is Unity, then you will have to create the materials in Unity no matter what. So why spend time to recreate them in Blender first?

Comment: IDK why you want to use nodes, but if you are looking to reduce the texture count, there is an atlas tool, forgot where, but it's an addon that doesn't ship with Blender (yet).

Comment: Im not needing to reduce texture count, just create a material using the textures I have. That addon might be called MatsCombiner, and it doesn't work with 2.8 yet.
I can and have created the materials in Unity, but it needs to be atlased together to take it down to one total material to follow VRChat model guidelines